# How to load parameters from file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm creating several flows that all use the same parameters. However, I have over 100 values that I need as parameters.
Is there anyway to load them from a file?
I need this specially because everything will be saved in a repository, and I want people that clone to have the parameters in their NiFi without having to do anything else.
Thank you.

I already tried parameter contexts, but I have to edit them by hand and I wanted an automatic solution.